# Ultimate Cron Background Process Taking a Long Time

Tags: cron

I'm having background process on Ultimate Cron process various queue items, but the fastest it usually processes them is at least one minute, and sometimes 3 minutes per item.

This seems incredibly slow to me.

Should I increase the number of threads? I'm not finding much documentation on how to speed up the process - I don't mind if it requires a bit more processing power - this is a required operation for the Drupal install in question, and it has to be run pretty much all the way through every 15 minutes.

There are no errors, just very slow processing.

Answer (score -2):

I think we need to check from start to end point. This issue is like some processes which takes more time to execute. So we need to check what is that process and we can find that using [Elysia Cron](https://www.drupal.org/project/elysia_cron) plugin.

This plugin helps you to find which cron process has taken much time and where to take possible actions.

PS: If this stuff helps you please leave me a comment and support :)

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know that Elysia Cron will help when I am trying to use Ultimate Cron. As far as I can tell, they are two modules that do mostly the same thing.